# What should I do to make people at least see my question?

Tags: support

This is my first question at meta, and I was really confused what to do when my question only got 9 views.

The link to the question : [Maximum product of lengths involving secant drawn to a parabola.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047026/)

I guess the only way to make people see the question is to place a bounty on it, but I am not so sure on it since it might turn out to be a bad question and may not be worth of my hard earned reputation.

I just don't want to take the risk of placing a bounty on it. The question didn't get many views, so I have no idea how will the community react to it when I would place a bounty on it.

I also thought of flagging the question, but I guess it's only when there is a real problem with it.

I am clueless about what to do. Can I "enhance" my question? Can I do something to make this question interesting? What should I do to somehow "promote" my question?

Comment: Perhaps the title can be improved. Looking at your link above did not make a clear impression of what your Question is about.  If I'm not

Comment: @hardmath you're not?

Comment: ...clear, then I'm less likely to click through.

Comment: Any suggestions about a suitable title then? And your thoughts about the way of framing the question or the question itself??

Comment: A popular solution to the problem of not getting enough views is to make post on Meta asking why your question didn't get enough views. It's certainly worked for others in the past. :)

Comment: It ain't working in this case @Rahul :)

Comment: I have tried my hand at revising your title.  Note that while the Question literally asks to maximize $|t|$, but given the constraint $PA\cdot PB = 3|t|$, this amounts to maximizing the product of lengths $PA$ and $PB$.

Comment: Do *not* flag a question because it did not get enough views.

Comment: @hardmath, my intention was to show t was to be maximized, inferring that the point P(1,t) was too be maximized. But still thanks for revising the title.

Comment: It's your Question, and I only undertook a revision to help you think "laterally" about expressing the problem concisely.  Asking to "maximize the value of a point" was confusing to me, but I did understand you were thinking about the height of the point after studying the body of the Question.

Comment: I guess this confusion was the reason why there were less views. Thanks once again for reviewing the title of my original question. But, if I have to promote my question, what should I do? Post here about it?

Comment: You could always hire a mathematical consultant to work on your problem.

Comment: @Rohinb97: Please, don't post here every time you want more views to your question.  If you "have to" promote your question, you can edit to improve it, or start a bounty.  Neither is guaranteed to work, but as far as means within this website, that is all there is.  You could promote it through social media I suppose.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @JonasMeyer.